# How to add one class into button of odoo v8

Tags: odoo-8

I want to add external CSS file into Odoo v8. My CSS change style of button.

How to change:

```
<button type="button" class="oe_button oe_form_button oe_highlight">...</button>
```

by:

```
<button type="button" class="oe_button oe_form_button oe_highlight new_class">...</button>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the button definition by inheriting it from the parent view which contains it. So first you need to find the parent view which contains that button, then inherit it in your custom view and finally replace the button with your custom button using xpath or using field catch method.

E.g

```
<record id="xyz_view_id" model="ir.ui.view">
   <field name="name">mrp.production.form</field> <!-- name of the view change it to your desire -->
   <field name="model">mrp.production</field> <!-- model of the view change it to your desired one -->
   <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp.view_mrp_form_abc"/> <!-- parent view which contains the button def -->
   <field name="arch" type="xml">
       <xpath expr="//button[@class='oe_button oe_form_button oe_highlight']" position="replace">
             <button type="button" class="oe_button oe_form_button oe_highlight new_class">...</button>
       </xpath>
   </field>
<record>
```

Comment: impossible if i want to add class into all button of odoo?

Comment: What about using xpath expr=" //button" you can also inherit field_view_get method to accomplish this.